# Creating Menu that allows to hide or unhide 2 different columns if their value is equal to 0 in Google Doc Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a google doc that has formulas in column C and Column D. It's a forecasting sheet so I know what we have on hand (C) and what we have on order (D). I want a script that opens a menu at the top so I can quickly hide or unhide Column C values that are equal to 0 and the same with column D.

I've pulled this script from someone on here to create a menu for hiding rows but I can't get it to work with my application. I'm not sure if the formulas in the cells prevent the function from finding 0's or not.

UPDATE: I have the first function working. It hides all rows with a 0 in column C. When a row is hidden and is updated to have a value, the function does not unhide it though. The second function is still not unhiding all. Once I get these two figured out I can build out the same thing for Column D. Below is updated script

```
 function onOpen() {
// get active spreadsheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// create menu
var menu = [{name: "Show Only On Hand", functionName: "hideRow"},
  {name: "Show All", functionName: "showRow"}];

// add to menu
ss.addMenu("Filter", menu);
}

function hideRow() {
// get active spreadsheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// get first sheet
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Inventory')

// get data
var data = sheet.getDataRange();

// get number of rows
var lastRow = data.getLastRow()+1;

Logger.log(lastRow);

// itterate through rows
for(var i=1; i<lastRow; i++) {
 if(data.getCell(i, 3).getValue() == 0) {
    sheet.hideRows(i);
 }
}
}

function showRow() {
// get active spreadsheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// get first sheet
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// get data
var data = sheet.getDataRange();

// get number of rows
var lastRow = data.getLastRow();

// show all rows
sheet.showRows(lastRow, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't do everything for you, cause this isn't this sites goal, but I'll point to where the script could be failing,  by line:

```
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
```

Is it always the first sheet you're using? If not, you can use the method `getSheetByName()`.

```
for(var i=1; i<lastCol; i++) {
```

This iterates trough the columns, do you really want that? If it is for rows, you'll need to change the `getLastColumn` for a row method.

```
if(data.getCell(i, 3).getValue() == '0') {
```

Again, if it is row that you want to hide, you'll have to refactor getCell, since i is the row, and 3 is the column, you can add another conditional since you also want column D.
Also, you may need to log the `data.getCell()` to check if the 0 is really coming as a String, if it is coming as a number remove the single quotes.

```
sheet.hideColumns(i);
```

Again, for row, this need to be refactored.

Update:

To show all you can:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var fullSheetRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns() )  
sheet.unhideColumn( fullSheetRange );
sheet.unhideRow( fullSheetRange ) ;
```

And then hide them. To do this for column all you have to do is copy and change the column C specied in `getCell()`, you can add another condition in the if with the [OR logical operator](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp).

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused as to why I wouldn't want the Columns since it's column c that my data is on.

Comment: You want to hide the entire column or just rows? If you hide column C, if any value in the C column is 0, it'll hide it entirely, it doesn't seem logical, since the trouble of hiding both columns is less or equal of going into the menu and selecting the function, but to hide several rows, then it would be better.

Comment: Really the only thing I need in the function now is for the first function to also look up values that might have been hidden from running it previously but now have a value and unhide the value. I tried to add some if statements but nothing seems to work. Any hints on that?

Comment: Unhide all before re-hidding.

Comment: I tried adding // itterate through rows
for(var i=1; i<lastRow; i++) {
 if(data.getCell(i, 3).getValue() <> 0) {
    sheet.unhideRows(i);  But still wouldn't work. Any ideas how to say not equal to 0

Answer (score 0):

Huge thanks to Kriggs for helping me figure this one out. I'm sure it's a bit clunky, but it works perfect for what I need.

```
function onOpen() {
// get active spreadsheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// create menu
var menu = [{name: "Show Only On Hand", functionName: "hideRow"},
            {name: "Show Only On Order", functionName: "hideorder"}];

// add to menu
ss.addMenu("Filter", menu);
}

function hideRow() {
// get active spreadsheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// get first sheet
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Inventory')

// get data
var data = sheet.getDataRange();

// get number of rows
var lastRow = data.getLastRow()+1;

Logger.log(lastRow);

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var fullSheetRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns() )  
sheet.unhideColumn( fullSheetRange );
sheet.unhideRow( fullSheetRange ) ;

  // itterate through rows
for(var i=1; i<lastRow; i++) {
 if(data.getCell(i, 3).getValue() == 0) {
    sheet.hideRows(i);
 }
}
}

function hideorder() {
// get active spreadsheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// get first sheet
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Inventory');

// get data
var data = sheet.getDataRange();

// get number of rows
var lastRow = data.getLastRow()+1;

Logger.log(lastRow);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var fullSheetRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns() )  
sheet.unhideColumn( fullSheetRange );
sheet.unhideRow( fullSheetRange ) ;

// itterate through rows
for(var i=1; i<lastRow; i++) {
 if(data.getCell(i, 4).getValue() == 0) {
    sheet.hideRows(i);
 }
}
}
```